# add list of lists to pandas dataframe, where each item of the list is a new column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

I have 10 list of lists (variable length) looking like this, but each inside list is of the same length.

```
[[0.2908717393875122, 0.012684155255556107, -0.0040715765208005905], [0.02942436747252941, 0.011299843899905682, 0.009102505631744862], [0.0382646806538105, 0.004623611457645893, 0.004776048939675093]]
```

I also have a list of 10 dataframes, where each df looks like this:

```
Second | Number |
2      |   B    |
3      |   B    |
4      |   B    |
```

What I would like to do is add this list of list to each dataframe, where the resutls looks like this:

```
 Second    | Number | V1                | V2                  |V3
    2      |   B    |0.2908717393875122 |0.012684155255556107 | -0.0040715765208005905
    3      |   B    |0.02942436747252941| 0.011299843899905682| 0.009102505631744862
    4      |   B    |0.0382646806538105 | 0.004623611457645893| 0.004776048939675093
```

I know how to append a single list to the existing dataframe (and it works), but I would like to to do this all in one go.

```
df['V1'] = list
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lst=[[0.2908717393875122, 0.012684155255556107, -0.0040715765208005905], [0.02942436747252941, 0.011299843899905682, 0.009102505631744862], [0.0382646806538105, 0.004623611457645893, 0.004776048939675093]]
```

Just simply use:-

```
df[['V1','V2','V3']]=lst
```

Now if you print `df` you will get your desired output:-

```
 Second Number  V1              V2          V3
0   2      B    0.290872    0.012684    -0.004072
1   3      B    0.029424    0.011300    0.009103
2   4      B    0.038265    0.004624    0.004776
```

**Edit by @msa**:

```
first: new_cols = ['V1', 'V2', 'V3'] 
df = df.reindex(df.columns.union(new_cols), axis=1)
```

Comment: Hi there this one only works if I add the column names first: new_cols = ['V1', 'V2', 'V3']
    df = df.reindex(df.columns.union(new_cols), axis=1) - maybe add it to the solution?

Comment: added to the solution....after doing this is it working for you...I mean are you getting your expected output

Comment: yes I'm - just waiting to verify the tick for you!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
for i in range(10):
    d = pd.DataFrame(list_of_list[i], 
                     columns=['V1','V2','V3'],
                     index=list_df[i].index)
    list_df[i] = list_df[i].join(d)
```

Comment: Hi there - how would this work for an already existing df?